# Adding to SwiftData from a global array, not working as expected

Tags: arrays, swiftui, global, swift-data

This is the most basic of SwiftData setups, I started looking at this after encountering a problem in a much larger app. In the sample below the issue is that if you press the "Zoo" button multiple times it only adds one "LION" and one "GOAT". If you add a print the function is correctly called, if you move the GLOBAL_ZOO array local to the function it works as expected. I am assuming that this is a foible of SwiftData or maybe a bug as the framework is so new, but I was just curious in anyone had come across this or had any wisdom on what might be happening?

```
// MARK: - TESTBED GLOBAL
let GLOBAL_ZOO = [Animal(name: "LION"), Animal(name: "GOAT")]

// MARK: - TESTBED CONTENT
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query var animals: [Animal]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(animals) { each in
                Text("\(each.name)")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Animals")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button("Add", action: addAnimals)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button("Zoo", action: zooAnimals)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Del", action: delAnimals)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func zooAnimals() {
        for each in GLOBAL_ZOO {
            context.insert(each)
        }
    }
    
    func addAnimals() {
        let one = Animal(name: "FRED")
        let two = Animal(name: "BERT")
        context.insert(one)
        context.insert(two)
    }
    
    func delAnimals() {
        for each in animals {
            context.delete(each)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A global object will always be the same instance and have the same id so SwiftData will identify it as already existing and perform an update instead of an insert (or even do nothing because the new and existing one are identical). At least that’s my theory of why you get this behavior. Activating Core Data debug logging might give some insight on this.

Comment: Hi Joakim, thank you for the reply, that sounds very plausible, ill do some more digging.

Comment: I Joakim, would you like to move that comment to an answer, and ill mark it as accepted +500 for your time and effort ?

Answer (score 2):

A global object will always be the same instance and have the same id so SwiftData will identify it as already existing and perform an update instead of an insert (or even do nothing because the new and existing one are identical).

Running the example from the question with Core Data debug logging turned on clearly shows that nothing after adding the global objects a second time.